# ng-model show / hide for label or a tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have below code

```
<div class="tabs DeliveryRightDiv">

            <label class="selected"><a>One</a></label>
            <label> <a>Two</a> </label>
            <label> <a>Three</a></label>

   </div>
```

I have one div which display on basis of use have selected one/ two/three from above a tag

```
  <div flex layout="row" class= "mycls">
   <div flex  layout="row" id="myid">
            <div flex  layout="column" class="insideall">
                <label>{{Oneselectedvalue}}<span>Total </span></label>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

When the user selects Two, expression value should be `{{Twoselectedvalue}}` instead of `{{Oneselectedvalue}}` (All values reside in the controller ).

I have tried adding model but unlike input box, I don't have any value to compare for show hide !! Is there any suggestion that its possible with one div like this?

Comment: in controller set Oneselectedvalue value as Twoselectedvalue?

Comment: Can you please give in details ?

Comment: Can you please update details ?

Comment: yes in controller when is Twoselectred then  $scope.Oneselectedvalue= $scope.Twoselectedvalue

Comment: can you put controller code necessary ?

Comment: in controller I have all values of oneseltecdvalue / twoselectedvalue in scope

Comment: please put some code for help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this (create a var "selectedvalue" in your controller) :

```
<div class="tabs DeliveryRightDiv">

        <label class="selected"><a ng-click="selectedvalue = 1">One</a></label>
        <label> <a ng-click="selectedvalue = 2">Two</a> </label>
        <label> <a ng-click="selectedvalue = 3">Three</a></label>

</div>
```

Then

```
<div flex layout="row" class= "mycls">
    <div flex  layout="row" id="myid">
        <div flex  layout="column" class="insideall">
            <span ng-hide="selectedvalue != 1"><label>{{Oneselectedvalue}}<span>Total </span></label></span>
            <span ng-hide="selectedvalue != 2"><label>{{Twoselectedvalue}}<span>Total </span></label></span>
            <span ng-hide="selectedvalue != 3"><label>{{Threeselectedvalue}}<span>Total </span></label></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ng-click to initialize a variable called "selectedvalue" with value wanted (1 for one, 2 for two, etc.), then using ng-hide to show the one you selected.

I can't test it on Angular 1.x so tell me if it worked for you (working on angular 4).

Comment: Hey @addict ,thanks !! Thats perfectly running for me !! but issue is for first one, its not showing on on-load because seems nothing get selected it got !! and when I trry to update it with (ng-show when 2 and 3 is not selected ), its shown on load, but problem is its not hide when selecting 2 or 3 even ?? Is there anything I can add here

Comment: I'm close to understand your problem but can you send us a gif or pics showing it ? It'd help me a lot to understand what you're trying to do

Comment: Hey , ITs done !! Thanks a lot !! Accepting this ans as valid